# How to prevent ffmpeg from dropping frames when trimming?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, vlc

I'm using ffmpeg to trim a Zoom video recording (format: ISO Media, MP4 v2 [ISO 14496-14]) via this command:

```
ffmpeg \
  -ss 00:11:42 \
  -to 01:11:22 \
  -i input-original.mp4 \
  -c copy \
  output-trimmed.mp4
```

The input file looks great, but the output has a few dropped frames at the beginning, so for the first few seconds it looks like this:

[image]

A few seconds later, it goes back to normal and it doesn't have any other issues. I'm wondering if there is a way to fix this problem.

EDIT: Actually, this seems to be a VLC-specific problem. Once I upload it to Vimeo, the weird frames go away. Still, I'd like to know if there is a way to prevent this.

Comment: It's probably not a FFmpeg issue — the resulting video should be good (if the source was good, naturally). Try `ffplay output-trimmed.mp4` for playing it back.

Answer (score 3):

Try to place the `-ss` and `-to` after the input:

```
ffmpeg \
  -i input-original.mp4 \
  -ss 00:11:42 \
  -to 01:11:22 \
  -c copy \
  output-trimmed.mp4
```

According to @Gyan (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45004159/ffmpeg-ss-and-t-for-cutting-mp3)

> When -ss and -t are placed before the input, ffmpeg resorts to fast
>   seek which relies on the index of the input to allow ffmpeg to start
>   and stop seeking. MP3s don't have indices, so ffmpeg estimates
>   duration via bitrate. This can be inaccurate.
>
> When -ss and -t are placed after the input, ffmpeg counts demuxed
>   packets. This will be accurate.

If it doesn't work you can also try to convert your video to intra-frame format (try `ffvhuff`), trim it and then convert it back to mp4 but this will slightly decrease the quality of the trimmed output. Keep in mind that `ffvhuff` will create huge file in size so make sure you have enough free space if you want to go this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired video without any broken or black frames by decoding and re-encoding the video. Although you need to know video codec and bit-rate in order to achieve so

```
ffmpeg -i input-original.mp4 -ss 00:11:42 -strict -2 -to 01:11:22 -codec:v h264 -b:v 100k;
```

*Note:* If this does not work, try to change `-to` switch to `-t` and specify the duration.
Hope this helps.